# Add element to array if not exists, increment a value in the element if element already exists in the array

Tags: mongodb

The mongodb collection looks like the array below

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arr": [
      {
        "key": "abc",
        "val_a": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2
  }
]
```

What I want to do is increment 1 to the element in `arr` array with `key` `def`. If the element with `key` `def` is not in the array `arr`, I want to add a new element like below to `arr`

```
{
    "key": "def",
    "val_a": 1
}
```

I tried

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "arr.key": "def",
  
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "arr.$.val_a": 1
  }
})
```

But it is not adding the new element. The result is like

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arr": [
      {
        "key": "abc",
        "val_a": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2
  }
]
```

What I am expecting is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arr": [
      {
        "key": "abc",
        "val_a": 2
      },
      {
        "key": "def",
        "val_a": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to do it in one operation as I am intending to do is a `BulkWrite` operation with `UpdateOneModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- finds the `_id`
- new-member you set any document to add
- if arr is not array make it an empty array, so concat to work later
- check if it exists
- if not exists, add to the end of the array
- else map to find it and increase its `val_a`

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=624d6788f7e3c64c6511e167)

*this is pipeline update, to do it with 1 query, alternative way is with 2 queries, one to check if it exists, and the second to `$push` (if not exists) or to `$set` with arrayFilters.
(you would had to send 2 queries and write 3 queries, and its not atomic safe)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
[{"$set": {"new-member": {"key": "abc", "val_a": 1}}},
 {"$set": {"arr": {"$cond": [{"$isArray": ["$arr"]}, "$arr", []]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"not-exists": 
     {"$eq": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": "$arr",
            "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.key", "$new-member.key"]}}},
         []]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"arr": 
     {"$cond": 
       ["$not-exists", {"$concatArrays": ["$arr", ["$new-member"]]},
         {"$map": 
           {"input": "$arr",
            "in": 
             {"$cond": 
               [{"$eq": ["$$this.key", "$new-member.key"]},
                 {"$mergeObjects": 
                   ["$$this", {"val_a": {"$add": ["$$this.val_a", 1]}}]},
                "$$this"]}}}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["new-member", "not-exists"]}])
```